# Three-fold repetitions

Tags: blessing

What’s the deal with Judaism and saying things 3 times in a row? Like in the end of Tefilat Haderech we repeat a pasuk 3 times, by Kiddish Levanah we repeat a lot of things 3 times (like “shalom alecheim” and “david melech yisrael chai vkayam”), and especially right before we sleep after Hamapil we say a few things 3 times in a row (רגזו, בשם ה׳, הנה לא, לישועתך). So like why, does saying something 3 times in a row have some special effect? And why in these places specifically?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62366/why-do-we-recite-shlosh-esrei-middos-3-times-during-the-pre-torah-service-on-th

Comment: I had a rebbi that once told me to be wary of such introductions into the text of tefillah, that when something is repeated three or seven times it is often intended to utilize the text as an incantation rather than for tefillah (i.e. to produce magical effect rather than as a mechanism of self-perfection) and that accordingly many early nushaoth do not have them